# Simple button for mashup script

Tags: python, scripting

I am creating a script from all sort of sources, I am no coder, so I am sure it is ugly, but it does the trick.
The issue is with the button operator, when running the code it works fine, but when I click on the panel button that has been created in the UI I get error messages that are just beyond me.

This is where I got with the button script + operator:
Thanks!

```
import bpy

class _OT_SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Creates GLB setup after baking"""
    bl_idname = "object.after_bake_setup"
    bl_label = "After Bake Setup"


    def execute(self, context):

        #Materials Remove, Add material using object's name
        selectedObject = bpy.context.selected_objects
        print (selectedObject)

        listOfObj=[]
        for obj in selectedObject:
            listOfObj.append(obj)
            obj = bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active
            for x in obj.material_slots:
                obj.active_material_index = 0
                bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove()


        #UV's - Remove all UV's except for the 'bake' (option for list ones on 'names')
        def rem_uvs(uvs_to_keep, ob):
            uvs_to_rem = []
            if type(uvs_to_keep) == 'str':
                uvs_to_keep = list(uvs_to_keep)
            if ob.type != 'MESH':
                return
            for uv in ob.data.uv_layers:
                if uv.name in uvs_to_keep:
                    continue
                uvs_to_rem.append(uv)
            while uvs_to_rem:
                ob.data.uv_layers.remove(uvs_to_rem.pop())


        # providing single name to keep
        rem_uvs("baked", bpy.context.object)

        # providing list of names to keep
        #names = [
        #    "bake",
        #    "Combined",
        #    "Normal",
        #    ]
        #rem_uvs(names, bpy.context.object)

        obj = bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active
        newMaterial = bpy.data.materials.new(name=obj.name)

        obj.data.materials.append(newMaterial)

        #Material Node Setup
        newMaterial.use_nodes = True
        principled_node = newMaterial.node_tree.nodes.get('Principled BSDF')

        image_texture_node = bpy.context.object.active_material.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')
        image_texture_node.location = (-300, 300)
        newMaterial.node_tree.links.new(image_texture_node.outputs[0], principled_node.inputs[0])

        uv_map_node = bpy.context.object.active_material.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeUVMap')
        uv_map_node.location = (-520, 300)
        newMaterial.node_tree.links.new(uv_map_node.outputs[0], image_texture_node.inputs[0])
        uv_map_node.uv_map = "bake"


class _PT_LayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the scene context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "Layout Demo"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        scene = context.scene


        # Big render button
        layout.label(text="Big Button:")
        row = layout.row()
        row.scale_y = 2.0
        row.operator("object.after_bake_setup")



def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(_OT_SimpleOperator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(_PT_LayoutDemoPanel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(_OT_SimpleOperator)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(_PT_LayoutDemoPanel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

The error I'm getting, I'm pretty sure this is going to be only one of few, I think when putting the code in a class it messes up calling some of the functions.. The code (the execute) on its own works fine when running from the text editor.

[image]

after adding poll as I can see on blender python templates ('operator simple)
I get this error: something to do with context incorrect

```
location: <unknown location>:-1
Error: Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\AfterBake_Addon_2.py", line 26, in execute
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.92\2.92\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 132, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove.poll() failed, context is incorrect
```

Comment: Hello, copy pasting the error thrown in the console will help pinpoint the issue :)

Comment: @Gorgious I have added the error message to the post.

Comment: Give the operator a poll method such that it doesn't poll (cannot be run) when `context.object is None` ---> this being the case is  producing the error mentioned in question.  _`context.object` is none for example after delete operator is run_

Comment: @batFINGER I still get this error regarding the context, what still make me think that when putting the code inside the execute operator I loose the active object somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edits.**

- Please never post code as image.
- Using `context.object` in the properties can be dodgy as
  (speculating) it is also used to pin an object. Printing will show it
  is often `None`, this was causing the polling error with remove
  material slot operator.
- To remove all the materials from selected objects can override the
  operator to pass the non (or) context object to it directly. *Suggest
  this could be a logic error as it will simply clear all materials of
  the selected objects, whereas perhaps you desire to do same to all.*
- There is no need to tack a `_PT` or `_OT` onto the name of classes.
  Let the `bl_idname` do this for us, for operators "foo.bar" ->
  "FOO_OT_bar".
- The operator has to return a status set, eg `{'FINISHED'}` if run
  successfully.
- If we poll that the active object need be, and need be a mesh there
  need be no need to test in code.
- Use the `context` argument passed to an operator, there is **never** a
  need to see `bpy.context` in operator or panel code.
- On a semantics side, and recommended in best practice, stick to lower
  case variable names, `active_obj` over `activeObj`. The latter is
  reminiscent of blender circa  *"python 2.x"*
- IMO good practice to put all our registerable classes in a list. This
  comes in very handy both when adding new classes, and when inspecting
  the addon.

Code revamp.

```
import bpy

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Creates GLB setup after baking"""
    bl_idname = "object.after_bake_setup"
    bl_label = "After Bake Setup"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        ob = context.active_object
        return ob and ob.type == 'MESH'
    
    def execute(self, context):

        for obj in context.selected_objects:
            if obj.type != 'MESH':
                continue

            while obj.material_slots:
                obj.active_material_index = 0
                bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove({"object" : obj})


        def rem_uvs(uvs_to_keep, ob):
            uvs_to_rem = []
            if type(uvs_to_keep) == 'str':
                uvs_to_keep = list(uvs_to_keep)
            for uv in ob.data.uv_layers:
                if uv.name in uvs_to_keep:
                    continue
                uvs_to_rem.append(uv)
            while uvs_to_rem:
                ob.data.uv_layers.remove(uvs_to_rem.pop())


        # providing single name to keep
        obj = context.active_object
        rem_uvs("baked", obj)

        mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name=obj.name)

        obj.data.materials.append(mat)

        #Material Node Setup
        mat.use_nodes = True
        principled_node = mat.node_tree.nodes.get('Principled BSDF')

        image_texture_node = mat.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')
        image_texture_node.location = (-300, 300)
        mat.node_tree.links.new(image_texture_node.outputs[0], principled_node.inputs[0])

        uv_map_node = mat.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeUVMap')
        uv_map_node.location = (-520, 300)
        mat.node_tree.links.new(uv_map_node.outputs[0], image_texture_node.inputs[0])
        uv_map_node.uv_map = "bake"
        return {'FINISHED'}


class LayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the scene context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "Layout Demo"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        scene = context.scene


        # Big render button
        layout.label(text="Big Button:")
        row = layout.row()
        row.scale_y = 2.0
        row.operator("object.after_bake_setup")


classes = (
        SimpleOperator,
        LayoutDemoPanel
        )
        
def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)

def unregister():
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Thanks so much for that, works perfect.
I will have to look through the code a bit longer to see what you've done there.
many thanks.

Comment: NP, happy to help.